# Describe call inconsistent in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, describesobject, failing-tests, describefieldresult

In the Apex class below (executed in a client org), `testA()` passes while `testB()` fails. The failure is an assertion error from the `ServiceLayer` constructor.

```
/*  SF API 33  */
/*  PKG version 1.55  */
@isTest private class TestClass
{
    static testmethod void testA()
    {
        // setup test data A

        // call method that gets fields dynamically
        ServiceLayer l = new ServiceLayer();
    }

    static testmethod void testB()
    {
        // setup test data B

        // call method that gets fields dynamically
        ServiceLayer l = new ServiceLayer();
    }
} 

/*  SF API 33  */
/*  PKG version 1.55  */
global class ServiceLayer
{
    global ServiceLayer()
    {
        // get fields dynamically
        Set<String> fields = PKG.UtilityClass.getFields('MY__Object__c');
        System.assert(fields.contains('Name'));
    }
}
```

Code in the package PKG:

```
/*  SF API 27  */
global class UtilityClass
{
    global static Set<String> getFields(String sobjType)
    {
        // use basic describe calls to get SObject fields -no magic

        return fields;
    }
}
```

Basically when `testB()` runs the PKG code returns less fields than there are on the object (`Name` is one of them). But when the PKG code is called in Developer Console it returns the correct results. We also get no issues when the code utilizing `ServiceLayer` is executed as part of its business use-cases.

Now brace for the ridiculous punchline.

If I call the PKG code inside `testB()` the assertion passes.

```
    static testmethod void testB()
    {
        Set<String> fields = PKG.UtilityClass.getFields('MY__Object__c');
        System.assert(fields.contains('Name')); // passes 

        // same as before
        // assertion from ServiceLayer still fails
    }
```

Is there even an explanation to this? I'd be okay passing it as a mysterious issue with no answers.

UPDATE: specified the PKG version for the classes (they're all the same version).

Comment: Using asserts in production code smells of bad practice. Is that something you can remove?

Comment: It was added as part of debugging only.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar Issue, Your package class runs on API version 27.0 and rest all classes runs on 33.0, So There are things which affects your due to API change:-

**1. getGlobalDescribe() implementation change(API version 28.0):-**

Starting with Apex  saved using Salesforce.com API version 28.0, the keys in the map that getGlobalDescribe returns are always prefixed with the namespace, if any, of the code in which it is running. For example, if the code block that makes the getGlobalDescribe()   call is in namespace ffm, and a custom object named BillingLineGroup__c     is in the same namespace, the key returned is ffm_BillingLineGroup__c. For Apex     saved   using earlier API versions, the key contains the namespace only if the namespace of the code    block and the namespace of the sObject are different. For example,  if the code block that generates the map is in namespace ffm, and   an sObject is also in ffm, the key in the map is represented as     BillingLineGroup__c
    In Order to incorporate this change we have to add namespace prefix with the object name wherever we are retrieving object data from global description.

For Example:--
Use
private static Schema.SObjectType ffBillingLineGroupType  = s_mapGlobalDescribe.get(‘ffm_’+'BillingLineGroup__c');
Instead of 
private static Schema.SObjectType ffBillingLineGroupType  = s_mapGlobalDescribe.get('BillingLineGroup__c');

**2. There are two fields newly added in API version 28.0**

```
LastViewedDate
LastReferencedDate
```

**3. Developer console always runs with the latest API Version**

Comment: I am aware of those changes, and unfortunately none of them explain the inconsistency mentioned in the punchline. a) There are several fields missing when the PKG method is called from `ServiceLayer` ONLY when called from within that particular test method. b) Using API 27 on the calling classes has not made a difference. Btw I just updated my question to include the PKG version for the 2 calling classes (they're on the same version).

Comment: What i understand is that all the three classes(TestClass, ServiceLayer, UtilityClass) are inside same package "PKG version 1.55", Right?

Comment: Not right. Only `UtilityClass` is inside a package.