# Salesforce SOAP API getDescribes() strange behavior

Tags: soap-api, describesobject, describesobjectresult

I'm running into a very strange issue for a particular SOAP API Call [describeSObjects()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm) as oppossed to

[describesObject()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm) which gives varied result for a particular object.

There is an object DMAPP__DM_Collaboration_Map__c in my organization where my application queries for the object based on the fields available.

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, ... FROM DMAPP__DM_Collaboration_Map__c
```

The fields are obtained from the describeSObjects() call. Since my application queries for multiple objects, it utilizes this call in passing 100 objects together and retrieving the describes.

However, for this particular object the first call resulted in the object DMAPP__DM_Collaboration_Map__c having the field *LastViewedDate* whereas the second call does not have this field. Tried querying this and seems that the object does not have the LastViewedDate field. Well, you may ask that I could create a tab but that is not a feasible solution as my application deals with retrieving the data and there could be any number of objects that could have a similar issue.
One more observation is that when the first call describeSObjects() is passed with an array of size 1, it returns the object without the field LastModifiedDate. This could mean that if size is one it calls describeSObject() call. Is this in relation with the web service connector or with the service that returns the value?

I've waited on this issue for about 3 days to ensure that the field is deleted but it isn't.

Comment: Are you calling these methods from different API Versions?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AutiIAC and https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AvopIAC and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81879/describe-call-inconsistent-in-test-class. Ensure all your API versions are set to V28 or higher I believe

Comment: Using API v37.0. Tried on v39.0 and issue still exists.